# Why doesn't cv.waitKey(0) pause execution until key is pressed?

Tags: opencv3.0, opencv, python

I had thought `cv.waitKey` would pause execution until a key was pressed, but it doesn't seem to be doing so. When I run the following code:

```
import cv2 as cv

print("Start")
k = cv.waitKey(0)
print("Stop")
```

It does not wait for a key to be pressed before completing execution. Must there actually be an image shown for the delay to occur? Is there something (one of the many things) about event loop creation occurring, that I don't understand?

(Note: I'm not just looking for something to act as an 'input' line. I'm currently using OpenCV with an eyetracker and was trying to figure out why OpenCV seems to block the callback function of the eyetracker, when I ran into this misunderstanding.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a HighGUI window created and active(in focus):

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7

So the following would work (with imagefile.png some image on disk):

```
import cv2 as cv

print("Start")
image=cv.imread("imagefile.png")
cv.imshow("test",image)
k = cv.waitKey(0)
print("Stop")
```